# как заставить приложение iOS(objective-c) работать в бекграунде?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Задача - посылать на сервер местоположение юзера каждые Х секунд, приложение работает идеально, но в бекграунде спустя несколька минут, оно засыпает и перестаёт отправлять реквесты.

В Info.plist добавил:

Privacy - Location Always Usage Description,

Application does not run in background = NO

Required background modes =

```
                        App registers for location updates, 
                        App downloads content in response to push notifications, 
                        App provides Voice over IP services.
```

В Capabilities добавил Background Models: Location updates и VOIP.

Но ничего не помогает

Answer (score 0):

Вы не с того конца зашли. "Отправлять каждые X секунд" не получится, как ни старайтесь. Таймеры в бэкграунде отключаются. Приведённые Вами настройки позволят при изменении местоположения пользователя отправить обновлённую позицию на сервер. Всё более чем подробно описано здесь: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html